# Merging (two and a half) countries from maps-package to one map object in R

Tags: r, maps, spatial

I am looking for a map that combines Germany, Austria and parts of Switzerland together to one spatial object. This area should represent the German speaking areas in those three countries. I have some parts in place, but can not find a way to combine them. If there is a completely different solution to solve this problem, I am still interested.

I get the German and the Austrian map by:

```
require(maps)
germany <- map("world",regions="Germany",fill=TRUE,col="white") #get the map
austria <- map("world",regions="Austria",fill=TRUE,col="white") #get the map
```

Switzerland is more complicated, as I only need the 60-70% percent which mainly speak German. The cantones that do so (taken from the [census report](http://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/portal/de/index/themen/01/22/publ.html?publicationID=1737)) are

```
cantonesGerman = c("Uri", "Appenzell Innerrhoden", "Nidwalden", "Obwalden", "Appenzell Ausserrhoden", "Schwyz", "Lucerne", "Thurgau", "Solothurn", "Sankt Gallen", "Schaffhausen", "Basel-Landschaft", "Aargau", "Glarus", "Zug", "Zürich", "Basel-Stadt")
```

The cantone names can used together with data from [gadm.org/country](http://gadm.org/country) (selecting Switzerland & SpatialPolygonsDataFrame -> Level 1 or via the [direct link](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/rds/CHE_adm1.rds)) to get the German-speaking areas from the gadm-object:

```
gadmCH = readRDS("~/tmp/CHE_adm1.rds")

dataGermanSwiss <- gadmCH[gadmCH$NAME_1 %in% cantonesGerman,]
```

I am now missing the merging step to get this information together. The result should look like this:

[image: Result] It represents a combined map consisting of the contours of the merged area (Germany + Austria + ~70% of Switzerland), without borders between the countries. If adding and leaving out the inter-country borders would be parametrizable, that would be great but not a must have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can that like this:

Get the polygons you need

```
library(raster)
deu <- getData('GADM', country='DEU', level=0)
aut <- getData('GADM', country='AUT', level=0)
swi <- getData('GADM', country='CHE', level=1)
```

Subset the Swiss cantons (here an example list, not the correct one); there is no need for a loop for such things in R.

```
cantone <- c('Aargau', 'Appenzell Ausserrhoden', 'Appenzell Innerrhoden', 'Basel-Landschaft', 'Basel-Stadt', 'Sankt Gallen', 'Schaffhausen', 'Solothurn', 'Thurgau', 'Zürich')
GermanSwiss <- swi[swi$NAME_1 %in% cantone,]
```

Aggregate (dissolve) Swiss internal boundaries

```
GermanSwiss <- aggregate(GermanSwiss)
```

Combine the three countries and aggregate

```
german <- bind(deu, aut, GermanSwiss)
german <- aggregate(german)
```

Comment: You are of course right, I replaced the loop in my example by your code that uses subsetting.

Comment: An update: in R 3.5.1 bind is not working anymore for me. I replaced it with union, though imho all union takes only two arguments. Therefore the line with bind should be replaced by:
german <- union(deu, aut) 
german <- union(german, GermanSwiss)

Comment: The example above with `bind` works fine for me in R 3.5.1. You probably have another package loaded that hides the method? You can try the more explicit `raster::bind( )`